# No pages indexed or data available after verifying ownership in Google Search Console of website that has been around for a while

Tags: google-search-console

I'm taking over the management of a website that has been published since 2003. I verified ownership in Google Search Console, but there isn't any data available. I'm assuming there should be lots of data available since the site has been around for 13 years. Does it just take time for it to display in newly verified account, or is there something I can or need to do?

Comment: You only just signed up. Google does not keep this data for every site out there in hopes that they might sign up. It will take 30-60 days before any data they collect begins to make full sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google states that is will take time for data to start appearing [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2571221).

> When you add your site to Search Console, it may take some time before
>   diagnostic and other data is available. This is normal; it can take
>   some time for Search Console to gather and process data for your site.
>   In general, if you see a "No data yet" message, check back later. Once
>   Google starts crawling your site more often, you'll notice that Search
>   Console will begin to show more detailed data, and that this data is
>   updated more often.